# How to serialize an object that contains a list of other objects

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, serialization

How can I serialize an object that contains a list of other objects?

```
import json


class Foo:
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

class Bar:
  def __init__(self):
    self.z = 0
    self.foos = []

bar = Bar()
bar.foos.append(Foo(1, 2))

print(json.dumps(bar.__dict__))
```

**Output**

```
TypeError: <__main__.Foo instance at 0x024DD5F8> is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: What? That answer doesn't help me

Comment: In that answer there are recommendatins about using the `__dict__` field that I use already!

Comment: What do you expect the serialized output of `Foo` should be? A common way to do that is to implement your [JSONEncoder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)

Comment: @gdlmx `{"z": 0, "foos": [{"x": 1, "y": 2}]}`